# Array of Enemies, 2D Java Game

Tags: java

Basically, I am making a simple asteroids-y style side-scroller, I have had a little Java experience, but am not great when it comes to certain implementations.  So, I want to create a bunch of asteroids that spawn at random times and at random y-positions.  I figure the best way to do that is to do some sort of array, but I don't know how to really implement that, and do collision  checking for the entire array.  Here are relevant parts of my enemy and playing field classes.

Bonus points to whomever can help me get my theme music working!

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Enemy 
{
    int x, y;
    Image img;
    boolean isAlive = true;


    public Enemy(int startX, int startY, String location)
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        ImageIcon l = new ImageIcon(location);
        img = l.getImage();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, 60, 60);
    }
```

And

```java
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    Player p;
    Image img;
    Timer time;
    Thread animator;
    Enemy en1, en2;
    boolean lost = false;
    static Font font = new Font("SanSerif", Font.BOLD, 24);
    public AudioClip theme;

    public static int score = 0;
    public static int lives = 3;

    public Board() 
    {
        //theme = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("images/theme.mid"));
        //theme.play();
        p = new Player();       
        addKeyListener(new ActionListener());
        setFocusable(true);
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("images/background.png");
        img = i.getImage();
        time = new Timer(5, this);
        time.start();
        int v =  172;
        en1 = new Enemy(p.x + 600, 260, "images/enemy1.png");
        en2 = new Enemy(p.x + 600, 200, "images/asteroid.gif");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        checkCollisions();
        ArrayList bullets = Player.getBullets();

        for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            Bullet b = (Bullet)bullets.get(i);

            if(b.isVisible() == true)
            {
                b.move();
            }
            else
            {
                bullets.remove(i);
            }
        }

        p.move();

        if(p.x > 400)
        {
            en1.move(p.getdx());
        }
        if(p.x > 500)
        {
            en2.move(p.getdx());
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(lost)
        {
            System.out.println("You Lose");
        }
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if((p.getX() - 590) % 2400 == 0 || (p.getX() - 590) % 2400 == 1)
        {
            p.nx = 0;
        }
        if((p.getX() - 1790) % 2400 == 0 ||(p.getX() - 1790) % 2400 == 1)
        {
            p.nx2 = 0;
        }

        g2d.drawImage(img, 685-p.nx2, 0, null);

        if(p.getX() >= 590)
        {
            g2d.drawImage(img, 685-p.nx, 0, null);
        }

        g2d.drawImage(p.getImage(), p.edge, p.getY(), null);

        ArrayList bullets = Player.getBullets();
        for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
        {
            Bullet b = (Bullet)bullets.get(i);
            g2d.drawImage(b.getImg(), b.getX(), b.getY(), null);
        }
        if(p.x > 400)
        {
            if(en1.isAlive == true)
            {
                g2d.drawImage(en1.getImg(), en1.getX(), en1.getY(), null);
            }
        }
        if(p.x > 500)
        {
            if(en2.isAlive == true)
            {
                g2d.drawImage(en2.getImg(), en2.getX(), en2.getY(), null);
            }           
        }
    }
    public void checkCollisions()
    {
            Rectangle r1 = en1.getBounds();
            Rectangle r2 = en2.getBounds();
            ArrayList bullets = Player.getBullets();

            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
            {
                Bullet m = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
                Rectangle m1 = m.getBounds();

                if (r1.intersects(m1) && en1.isAlive())
                {
                    score++;
                    en1.isAlive = false;
                    m.visible = false;
                 }
                 else if (r2.intersects(m1)&& en2.isAlive())
                 {
                     en2.isAlive = false;
                     m.visible = false;
                 }
            }

            Rectangle d = p.getBounds();
            if (d.intersects(r1) || d.intersects(r2))
            {
            lives--;
                    if(lives < 0)
                    {
                        lost = true;
                    }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this tutorial on arrays:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

You also might want to consider an ArrayList, but since you are having difficulty with arrays, I would stick with the basics first.

Comment: I'm looking at array lists, they seem to be a way to create a nigh infinite supply of enemies.  I only want the game to end when the player is out of lives.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, I made a little Asteroids game.  There I used a Vector as a collection of Asteriord objects.  Then in the LaserBeam class (the starship has an laser gun!), I have something like this:

```
// collision with an asteroid?
for (Asteroid a : getAsteroids())
    if (a.getCp().getBounds2D().intersects(xPos, yPos, width, height))  
    {
        a.newHit();
        break;
    }
```

So the beam iterates through the asteroids and check if some one collides with the beam.  In that case, the life of the beam and the asteroid ends.

If you are interested, you can find the complete source code [here](http://federicocristina.com.ar/dev/asteroids/asteroids.zip), and [here](http://federicocristina.com.ar/dev/asteroids/index.html) is the applet game.